# Xcode hides warnings after recompile

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings

Take this scenario: after a compile from scratch of a Cocoa Touch project, Xcode may report several compiler warnings in different files.

If I fix the warnings in only one of the files and hit Build to see if it works, Xcode will no longer report any warnings in the other files (it will continue showing those in the currently open file if they're not fixed). If I manually switch to any of the other files I remember having warnings in, I can still see them reported correctly between the code lines. However they are not summarized in the Build Results screen, so I can't see an easy way of getting to these files.

This is normally a minor issue. But after a recent refactoring that produced ~50 warnings in about 20 files the problem started to get annoying.

Comment: Which version of Xcode you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you made your changes, X-Code did not build your entire project again, only what it needed and hence displayed only the warning relvant to the latest build.

If you go to the build results window command-shift-b you can configure it show you either latest results or all results.

Comment: I realize my project is not compiled for scratch unless I hit Clean. But I don't know how to configure the Build Results to show all the warnings

Comment: The option to select "all results" or "latest results" in the build window is a relatively new feature. It's in Xcode 3.2.1 but it may not be present in older versions.

Comment: @Paul you're right, I completely forgot that the build window was totally different in older versions

Comment: OK, I'm gonna consider this answer accepted. Looks like the only solution is to upgrade

Comment: There must be a solution for this in ver 3.1.4, but since I upgraded quite a while ago, I can't help you, sorry. I will say that the upgraded is well worth it. Tons of improvements in 3.2.

Comment: Unfortunately, Xcode 4.5 has re-introduced this bug - I have a project where I know this is happening (I introduced a deliberate compiler warning by deleting a referenced property ... and even deleting the build folder + restarting xcode has no effect (clean / clean build folder having already failed). Sob